# Correct way to input an integer then a string in c

Tags: newline, fgets

Having trouble getting input from keyboard when I get integer input then follow that by trying to input a string.  I think the fgets func is picking up the newline char from the previous input, but am not %100 sure what is going on.  Ideas?  Thanks!

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  int send;
  char message[100];
  printf("\nEnter your ID#: ");
  scanf("%d", &send);
  printf("Get string\n");
  fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
  printf("The string: %s\n", message);

}
```

resulting output

```
Enter your ID#: 23
Get words
The words:
```

fgets() inputs something and the resulting out put is whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Use a `getchar();` after the `scanf` and before the `fgets`. The reason why is because `scanf` reads what is specified (an integer in your case), then ignores the newline, which is subsequently fed to `fgets`. `getchar` "eats" this newline. See this link for a super detailed explanation 
http://www.go4expert.com/articles/solution-using-scanf-fgets-c-t27148/

Comment: @MikeD, ok, if the answer is what you're looking for it is then nice to accept it so someone else can benefit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The following line has an error:

```
fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
```

It should be

```
fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
```